# How do I keep words with spaces between them on the same line?

Tags: c

I am reading a text file, that contains the following words:

```
hi 
there
was it
fuzzy man lady
```

However, each time I print these out line by line I get the following:

```
hi 
there 
was 
it 
fuzzy 
man  
lady
```

I would like the words that are together to be on the same line like:

```
was it
fuzzy man lady
```

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {

    int i = 0, line = 7;
    char ch[200];

    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName,"r");
    while(line--){
        fscanf(file,"%s",ch);
        i++;
        printf("%s", ch);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
```

I'm guessing that the \n isn't discriminating when detecting a space or word on a new line. So how could I modify this to give the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line

```
fscanf(file,"%s",ch);
```

does not read a line of text. It reads only a word.

If you want to read a line of text, use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

```
fgets(ch, 200, file);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fread()` can also be used. Following will be able to read max 199 characters from the file.

```
fread(ch, sizeof(ch[0]), sizeof(ch)/sizeof(ch[0])-1, file);
```